# How to find the XPath for the below provided screenshot page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to click on the 4th element of the list it's an auto populate list and following code is not working.

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-text-as-pseudo-element='CORENA P 150']")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);`

[image]

Comment: How would you do this manually?  If you were to type part of the text and the drop-down shows the element you want four items down, you would either click that element by mouse or if you're sending a down-arrow keystroke, you'd need to send four of them, I would think, then a key.Enter

Answer (score 1):

You've got the * in the wrong place (end of line), haven't you? Add it after the // or use a div instead.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-text-as-pseudo-element='CORENA P 150']")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
```

Edit - Also looks like you could probably just use .click(); rather than .sendKeys(Keys.DOWN)?

Comment: Hi Klynt I tried in the manner above mentioned but still it's pointing as 3 nodes matching and not able to click it either ways.

Comment: If it's matching 3 nodes, does that mean that there are actually 3 entries on the page for "CORENA P 150"? As if so you'll need to be more precise. Alternatively try just matching on the text: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'CORENA P 150')]");